Is Phase Shift from Impedance Matching in Transducer Systems Acceptable?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In a transducer transmission system, if a matching circuit is placed before the transducer to minimize the reactive component seen by the power amplifier (so the amplifier sees a nearly purely resistive load- Zin), the voltage(Vload) and current(Iload) at the transducer may become out of phase after passing through the matching circuit. Is this phase difference at the transducer acceptable? Does it affect the system performance, even though the power amplifier sees an optimized (high power factor) load?

If the amplifier (on the left) sees a purely resistive impedance and, you have an efficient matching system then, the power delivered to the resistive element of the true load is maximized.
It may be that the terminal voltage across the true load and, the current into the true load are not-in-phase but, they are only not-in-phase in order to maximize power to the resistive element of the true load.

Is this phase difference at the transducer acceptable?

In order to drive optimum power to the true load's resistive element, the terminal voltage and current may not be in phase because of the complex nature of the terminal impedance of the true load.

As you said, does making the input impedance purely resistive automatically optimize power to the true load? If so, should I consider the matching circuit and transducer a unified system? Are there references supporting this, or is it based solely on fundamental principles? I'm still unsure how minimizing the reactance seen by Z_in ensures optimal power transfer to the load.

A properly designed low loss matching network guarantees that the power into the matching network from the driving source is all delivered to the resistive element of the true load (ignoring losses). You can consider the matching network and transducer (true load) a unified system.

I have a website that has a few commonly used matching networks. Some will be suitable: http://stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20home.html. They all have calculators and assume a resistive true load. To make a complex load into a resistive load requires a further modification aka tuning the load to make it appear resistive @kth

OP needs to explain what the entire system is.
If ultrasonic cleaning- phase matters not at all.
If an imaging system- OP needs to understand the relation between (matched) driving voltage and motion of the transducer surface. AND the propagation path. AND the receiving transducer where there may be different matching issues. AND the signal processing to obtain an image, if there are multiple receivers.
In the systems I am aware of relative phase matters rather than absolute phase.

The above system is for underwater active sonar systems. So, I am not considering the impedance magnitude matching but the phase difference minimization seen from the power amplifier terminal since the output resistance of PA is nearly 0.
